# Solving for a variable in an expression

Tags: quadratics

I have got this expression $X = 20t + 0.5t^2$ and the requirement for this is to solve for t. I have tried to do this by factoring t out but was not able to do it. 
This is what i have done:
$X = 20t + 0.5t^2\\$

$X = (0.5t +20)t $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying by $2$ we get
$$t^2+40t-2x=0$$
using the quadratic solution formula we get
$$t_{1,2}=-20\pm\sqrt{400+2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is a quadratic equation.